# How do I extend a field in a complex interface? TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, next.js, contentful

I have a large interface with a lot of nested objects as it is mapping out the response from the Contentful API. I want to be able to extend it for when I get different content types - which means the "fields" object within the interface is going to be different and I want to extend this part.

I would want to for example extend it with the BlogPost interface shown in code below.

Example of code is below:

```
export interface ContentfulEntry {
  metadata: {
    tags: [];
  };
  sys: {
    space: {};
    id: string;
    type: string;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
    environment: {
      sys: {};
    };
    revision: 1;
    contentType: {
      sys: {
        id: string;
        type: string;
        linkType: string;
      };
    };
    locale: string;
  };
  fields: {}; // WANT TO EXTEND THIS
}

export interface BlogPost {
  title: string;
  body: RichTextDocument | null;
  tags?: [CountryTag, RegionTag];
  images?: ContentfulImage[];
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

```
interface BlogPostEntry extends ContentfulEntry {
  fields: BlogPost;
}
```

Comment: You could start by extracting these "inner" properties into other interfaces. IE: `interface IMetaData { tags: []; }` then `interface ContentfulEntry { metadata: IMetaData; ... }` and so on.

Comment: Use a generic type parameter. `export interface ContentfulEntry<TFields> { fields: TFields; }`. And then `export type BlogPostEntry = ContentfulEntry<BlogPost>;`